# Internationalization of thousands of product labels in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

What would be the best way to internationalize thousands of product labels in Rails?
Should I enter all thousand labels in a YAML file? Or are there better solutions out there?

Any help will do :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails supports non YAML storage for translations. If you want to store the translations in a table, use the [i18n-active_record](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record) gem.

Watch the [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/256-i18n-backends) on customizable I18n backends.

If you use the [i18n-active_record](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record) gem, make sure to `memoize` and `flatten` the keys for optimal performance as shown below(code sample taken from [readme](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record/blob/master/README.textile) of [i18n-active_record](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record) gem)

```
I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord.new
I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Memoize)
I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Flatten)
I18n::Backend::Simple.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Memoize)
I18n::Backend::Simple.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Pluralization)
I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::Chain.new(I18n::Backend::Simple.new, I18n.backend)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a table called translations.

In your product model:

```
has_many :labels
```

In your Label model:

```
 has_one :translation
```

Then your translation table can have as many languages as you need:

```
 Product.first.labels.first.translation.en
 Product.first.labels.first.translation.cn
 Product.first.labels.first.translation.fn
```

With this logic you can call:

```
Product.all.each do |p|
    p.lables.each do |l|
        l.translation.en
        l.translation.cn
        #etc.... 
    end
end
```